# Configure date to UTC format

Tags: bash, date

There are a few answers to this that help with the gnome taskbar date-time display, and one answer that gives me exactly what I want, namely,

```
date +%Y-%m-%dT%T
```

which I've incorporated into .bashrc as an alias. Now, is there a way to change date permanently? Or do you always have to add these options? I'm afraid some programming I will do might not access a bash alias or I'll forget to add the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run your system with the `Universal` timezone, or use the `TZ` environment variable `env TZ=Universal date` .

Otherwise you are faced with configuring each application that 1) You use; and 2) displays the date.